# postgres index contains "unexpected zero page at block" exceptions

Tags: postgresql, logging, psql, pg

I have following errors in pg_log file several thousand times. How to resolve them.

```
index "meeting_pkey" contains unexpected zero page at block 410.Please REINDEX it.
index "faultevent_props_pkey" contains unexpected zero page at block 37290.
index "faultevent_pkey" contains unexpected zero page at block 1704
```

Comment: so far only indexes - viable, just rebuild them. next much more important identify how you killed those pages. do youhave backups?..

Comment: I don't have any backup. I am new to postgres. In which scenario we will get this kind of issue.This we are facing on of the perfomance check environment.

Comment: pages get corrupted on hardware failure mostly.

Answer (score 3):

The cause of the issue is due to bad index pages and its unable to read it.

Reindex the problematic index to overcome the issue.

```
 Reindex index <schema_name>.<index_name>;
```

[Here](http://kb.odin.com/en/117207) you have some hits.

Answer (score 1):

Your database is corrupt.

Try to run `pg_dumpall` to get a logical dump of the database.

If that fails, buy support from somebody who can salvage data from corrupted databases.

If it succeeds:

- Check the hardware, particularly storage and RAM.
- Once you are certain the hardware is ok, install the latest patch update for your PostgreSQL version.
- Create a new database cluster with `initdb`.
- Restore the dump into the new cluster.

Did you have crashes recently?
Did you test if your storage handles `fsync` requests properly?
Do you have any dangerous settings like `fsync = off`?

Comment: Did you have crashes recently?  No                                                                                                       
Did you test if your storage handles `fsync` requests properly?   How to test it?
Do you have any dangerous settings like `fsync = off`? its on.

Comment: Testing reliable storage is not trivial, but if there were no crashes it cannot be the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue and after a lot of reading I decided to do a complete DB reindex:

`reindex DATABASE <DATABASE NAME>`

and it solved the issue for me. Hope this helps you.